# How to display advanced custom fields with an if statement

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'd like to display advanced custom fields on my archive page only but the following code keeps giving me an error:

```
<?php
    do_action( 'editorial_post_categories' );
    if ( is_single() ) {
        // do something or nothing
    } else {
        <?php the_field('acf_123'); ?>
    }
?>
```

The advanced custom field I like to display is "acf_123"

Comment: Could you include the error you are receiving in the question please? That will help more in providing a solution.

Comment: @BenPlummer i get  a white screen and no error messaging when i visit my page.

Comment: You have an opening `<?php` tag and a closing `?>` tag in your `else` statement. Try removing those.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP's white screen of death](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475297/phps-white-screen-of-death)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're nesting `<?php` tags.  You've opened one at the top, so you don't need to open them again.  Try:

```
<?php
    do_action( 'editorial_post_categories' );
    if ( is_single() ) {
        // do something or nothing
    } else {
        the_field('acf_123');
    }
?>
```

That is, remove the `<?php` and `?>` around `the_field()` call.